# Threading a for loop in Spring MVC

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application. 
I need to implement threaded for loop.

The situation is described below.
There are multiple files in a folder and there are many folders.
Files have to be downloaded in parallel from each of the folders.
But files from a particular folder must be downloaded sequentially. ie 
If there are N folders, then at a point of time, N files will be downloaded simultaneously.

Sample code is given below

```
private FolderServiceManager folderServiceManager;
private FileRequestService fileRequestService;
......
......
@Override
public void downloadFiles(){
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    List<Folder> listOfFolders = folderServiceManager.getAllFolders();
    try {
        for (final Folder folder: listOfFolders) {
            exec.submit(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    fileRequestService.downloadMp4Files(folder);
                }
            });
        }
    } finally {
        exec.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The is no more of parallelization in any other code any where.

My question is that, whether the given code suits the purpose?

The scope of spring beans are the default ones. Do I need to change the scope of spring beans?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the code serves its purpose. You might want to consider handling long running threads if you believe that it may happen.

A different approach to solve the problem is to use the `CompletableFuture` class (Java 8). The code will be a bit cleaner (according to me).

```
    // Setup the Executor
    ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    // Create an array of all download jobs
    final CompletableFuture[] downloads = folderServiceManager.getAllFolders()
            .stream()
            .map(folder -> CompletableFuture.runAsync(
                () -> fileRequestService.downloadMp4Files(folder), exec)
             ) // Create the futures
            .toArray(size -> new CompletableFuture[size]); // Collect it as an array

    // If you want to wait for the futures to complete the allOf-method can be used.
    // If you don't want to wait you can skip these lines...
    final CompletableFuture<Void> allDownloads = CompletableFuture.allOf(downloads);
    allDownloads.get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) instead.

It will help you gain finer control over execution. Specifically you may want to have custom [RejectedExecutionHandler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RejectedExecutionHandler.html); as you are dealing with file system read there *are* good chances of long running / hung threads  which eventually may cause app irresponsive.